# Multiselect treeview of checkboxes on a mobile device?

Tags: mobile, hierarchy, multi-selection, jquerymobile

What is the best way of implementing something like this on a mobile device?

[image]

Which is an example of a multiselect dropdown box with a hierachy implemented in JQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/3jr2v/2/embedded/result/

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781905/jquery-multiselect-nested-option

I am using JQuery Mobile.

My requirements are:

- Around 5-30 checkboxes, depending on scenario
- Hierarchy that may be multiple levels deep (5?), and then the ability to deselect all children by clicking on the parent
- Doesn't make sense to use a 'autofill' 'autocomplete' control anywhere, as the user will not have any prior knowledge of what the options are

Some problems:

- If the checkboxes aren't nested in an accordion style, then it might end up being a really really long list of checkboxes
- If it is split into lists of checkboxes on different pages, how can I easily see a global view of everything that is selected? Is this too much effort?

I don't mind what the solution is, it doesn't have to be a single dropdown, it could be separate lists, pages... obviously screen real estate is at a premium. Anyone attempted something like this on a mobile device, or knows of any good examples?

Previous research:

- [Another way of doing multi-select on mobile other than check boxes?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38126/another-way-of-doing-multi-select-on-mobile-other-than-check-boxes/38129#38129)
- [tree-view for mobile devices](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5709/tree-view-for-mobile-devices)
- [For large hierarchies - checkbox tree or 'guided tree construction'](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8198/for-large-hierarchies-checkbox-tree-or-guided-tree-construction)
- [Multi Select hierarchy for Mobile Design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24252/multi-select-hierarchy-for-mobile-design)
- [File manager on a mobile device](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/file-manager-on-a-mobile-device)
- [What UI Should I Use?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38133/what-ui-should-i-use)
- [Multiselect for narrow display](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34456/multiselect-for-narrow-display)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I will go for such a solution.

If there is nested elements - give a visual cue.

If not - bypass

Hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks, so each parent item would be like an accordion? So multiple nested accordions, each with a slight indentation on the checkbox buttons beneath? I think this would be fairly complex to construct but looks good to me.

Comment: My pleasure, before implementing it, you can ask to some other people, i did not ask to anyone. It is indeed complex but maybe there can be an easier way...